# How to Add page navigation in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using GS Book Showcase Lite plugin for book store. I want to show page navigation after 6 book display so I'm using wp page-navi plugin.

But I don't know how to use wp page-navi in GS Book Showcase Lite plugin.

Answer (score 0):

display pagination by using wp-pagenavi

add below function in your template

```
 <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { // if PageNavi is activated ?>

<?php wp_pagenavi(); // Use PageNavi ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i have show the pagination using wp pagenavi but there is only one page show.hot to split post in multi page in my GS Book Showcase Lite plugin